# Best practices for updating software on a live server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, upgrade, live

Our live server running PHP v5.2.6 (yes, circa 2008) needs an upgrade.

I'm thinking the best process is:

1. Copying over all of our live sites to my personal server
2. Testing our sites on my personal server with the newest versions of all of our software
3. Making the versions on my server live (so that there are no interruptions in web access)
4. Upgrading to the newest versions of all of our software on our live server
5. Moving all of our sites back to our live server
6. Making the sites on our live server live again

Could you give me a better solution to this issue (if one exists)?

Comment: I don't think it is ever a good idea to use personal resources for a company process. Standing up a fresh server to test on that your company owns seems safer.

Comment: I should have included that we're a nonprofit so I try to do everything I can without costing the org much.

Comment: @runningonplants Do you own the server, or use some hosting service?

Comment: Linode is the hosting service that we use for our live server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this, and I recommend doing the following:

1. Purchase the new server (or start renting the production server - if you don't own it)
2. Move all the files over to the new server, but make sure that you make sure that Google cannot crawl the site. You don't want duplicate content on both websites running at the same time. You can do this by editing the /robots.txt file.
3. Get all the applications up and running with your new sites. (make sure everything works)
4. Enable Google to crawl the sites on your new server.
5. Disable Google to crawl on your OLD server.
6. If you are with the same hosting provider ask them to switch over the IP addresses to your new server. If they cannot do this then you will have to do it via DNS (which is more dangerous because if the is a problem it can take DNS 24 hours to switch back to the old server)
7. Let the server run for about a week, and if you see everything okay shutdown the old one.

To me it's more safe this option because I have experienced issues with moving to a new OS LAMP development, and this process let me work out the issues without the stress of worrying when I switched it over.

Comment: Thank you so much for that input. I actually contacted our hosting provider and they said we will only be charged per day so this is a GREAT plan. THANK YOU!

Comment: Your welcome just remember to enable the /robots.txt file when you are ready otherwise you will drop off the Google index.

Comment: this might be a silly question, but - on the new (not live YET) server, how do I test the sites without changing DNS?

Comment: You can either add an entry in the DNS for example:

testing.yoursite.com

or you can just go to it via ip address.